# Разархивирование архива формата .rar с помощью c#

Tags: c#, файлы, rar, winrar

Пытаюсь разархивировать png картинку через такой код.

```
Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", @"e D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\b.rar D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Game With Spaces");
```

Если у папки, в которую я делаю разархивирование есть пробелы в название, то вылетает ошибка rar: "Нет файлов для извлечения", как можно починить?

Comment: Возьмите путь в кавычки.

Comment: @tym32167   Вот так, что ли: Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", @"e D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\b.rar 'D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Game With Spaces'");

Comment: `Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", @"e \"D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\b.rar\" \"D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Game With Spaces\"");`

Comment: у меня ошибки летят, не корректно кавычки работают. Сам ничего не понимаю.

Comment: `Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", @"e ""D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\b.rar"" ""D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Game With Spaces""");`

Comment: вы святой человек, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", @"e ""D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\b.rar"" ""D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Game With Spaces""");
```

Comment: Дополните ответ деталями, как вы пришли к такому решению? Почему оно работает?